Converting argon2password using specific salt value so that it will give same value all the time
I have argon2password which is generated using automated salt value, due to this it is always giving different hashed code every time for same password.
I want to migrate the data of users, as a part of it i want encode the hashed password using the same salt value which is by us instead of automated.
I have tried to get the salt value from all ready generated argon2password value but not able to succeed in that

Keeping the salt the same should not be necessary, even for a migration scenario.
If the user supplies the correct password, the Argon2 implementation reads the salt dynamically during the validation process, and the password will match.
Unique salts per hash, even for the same password, are a critical security feature of password hashing and should not be disabled.
